# how to obtain the path of the current .scrbl file?

Tags: racket, scribble

Suppose I am running scribble on the file example.scrbl:

```
    scribble example.scrbl
```

I want to figure out the path, or at least the name, of the file which is being processed (in this case example.scrbl), programmatically inside the file itself.
I thought it would be

```
    (vector-ref 0 (current-command-line-arguments))
```

but this does not work. Actually, (current-command-line-arguments) returns empty vector. 
What is the right way? I want a function which would return the string "example.scrbl".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I very recently [blogged about](http://www.greghendershott.com/2014/06/-file-and-line-in-racket.html) you can use `(syntax-source #'here)` to get the pathname of the current source file.

To adapt that to Scribble you simply need to:

1. Use at-expressions.
2. Convert the `path` to a `string` for Scribble.

So:

```
#lang scribble/manual

This Scribble file is @(path->string (syntax-source #'here)).
```

Comment: Thank you. But the location of the source is not necessarily `example.scrbl`. I have `require` statements on the top of `example.scrbl`. All my procedures are defined there. For example, I have `(require helper.rkt)` at the top of `example.scrbl`. I have many procedures defined in that file `helper.rkt`. In defining those procedures, I can invoke `current-command-line-arguments` which gives my the information about how `scribble` was called (for example, if it was single page or multipage). But the name of the `.scrbl` file itself is not reported by `current-command-line-arguments`.

Comment: Your original question said, "I want to figure out the path, or at least the name, of the file which is being processed (in this case example.scrbl), programmatically _inside the file itself_." (emphasis mine). That's what I showed. If you have a different question, I'm sorry but I can't figure out what it is, from your comment. Maybe you could edit your question to show exactly what you want?

Comment: You are right. Seems like there is no ready solution. I guess I have to write a macro.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the path (without the filename) without resorting explicitly to syntax elements, by using [`runtime-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=define-runtime-path#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fruntime-path..rkt%29._define-runtime-path%29%29):

```
#lang racket
(require racket/runtime-path)

(define-runtime-path here (simplify-path (build-path 'same)))

(displayln here)
```